# 9p / virtfs : new files in shared folder don't belong to the expected user and group

Tags: libvirt, qemu, 9p

For the last two days I tried to share a folder between the host and a guest virtual machine, both running the latest Debian Stretch.

The folder I wish to share is owned by the `myuser`, group `mygroup` on the host hard drive (`/srv/sharedfolder`).
Since the guest is a LAMP server running Nextcloud I wish to access and write to this shared folder as `www-data:www-data`.

So I created a libvirt's filesystem with the `Default` driver and `Mapped` mode :

```
<filesystem type='mount' accessmode='mapped'>
    <source dir='/srv/sharedfolder'/>
    <target dir='sharedfolder'/>
    <alias name='fs0'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
</filesystem>
```

`Mapped` seems to be the good choice as written at [suse.com](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-12/book_virt/data/sec_libvirt_storage_share.html) :

> The user credentials and the client-user's credentials are saved in
>   extended attributes. This model is recommended when host and guest
>   domains should be kept completely isolated.

---

**On the host side** :

- user and group at `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` are set to `myuser` and `mygroup`
- the shared folder has been "chmoded" with `chmod 775`

**On the guest side** :

- the mountpoint of the shared folder belong to `www-data:www-data`
- fstab ([with kernel.org as reference](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/9p.txt)) :

  sharedfolder /srv/sharedfolder 9p trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L,rw,nofail 0 0

---

So far, **I can read and write the shared folder** as `www-data`, so the mission seems to be accomplished.

But when a new file is created on the host file by `myuser` within the shared folder the new file **is seen as owned by `myuser:myuser` by the guest** (whereas i expected it would be owned by `www-data:www-data`).

So what should I do ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What setup have you done on the host side to ensure the client-side UID/GID xattrs will be written?

Comment: As the humble home-sysadmin I am, I may not totally understand your question. I tried to apply the following xattrs to the shared folder (same command on both side), but without succes : `setfacl -R -m d:u:www-data:rw-,g:www-data:rw- /srv/sharedfolder` (`posixacl` has also been added to the fstab option of course)